# JavaをCMDで実行したときのPATHの問題

Tags: java, r, cmd

初めに文字で説明するのは苦手なので画像多用します。見にくかったら申し訳ないです。自分がやろうとしていることはEclipseで作ったJavaファイルをExportして実行することです。問題点はEclipseで作ったときにしっかりとPATHを設定し、Eclipse上では正常に動くのですがCMDではうまく動かないことです。
これが今回扱いたいコードです。JRIを使ってJava上でRという別の言語を扱います。Eclipse上では正常に6.0という値が求められました。
[image]

以下の二つの画像はBuild PATHとRun Configulationです
[image: Build PATH]
[image: Run Configulation]

このEclipseで作ったJavaファイルをExportします。(やり方間違っていたら嫌なので一応画像乗っけておきます。)
[image: Export]]

これを実行します。もしよろしければ以下の画像のように普通にjarファイルを実行できないわけも教えてほしいです。CMDでしか開けないです。普通に開けないこともうまく実行できない原因かもしれないなと思ってます。
[image: Can't run normally]

上の問題のせいで調べてみるとCMDなら実行できるということでしたのでCMDで実行しますが以下のようにうまくいきません。このエラーの意味はこちらの[サイト](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/xmldtp/e/c5edd25a19ef777d98e5546ea1da61ff)に書いてあります。
[image: CMD]

教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(jarファイルをダブルクリックで開くことに対する直接の回答ではありませんが)

- 今回作成した `jritest.jar`
- jri.dll
- 下記の通り作成した `jritest.bat`

の3ファイルを同じディレクトリに置いた上で `jritest.bat` をダブルクリックすれば実行できると思います。

`jritest.bat`の内容:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar jritest.jar.jar
```

Comment: こちらでやるとうまくダブルクリックでできました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

Rのdllを保持するディレクトリを起動時にシステムプロパティに積むか、環境変数PATHに積んでおく必要があります。
java -jar jritest.jar -Djava.library.path = "PATH TO JRI Instration Dir"
(ごめんなさいプロパティ指定の位置間違っているかもしれません）

以前私がサンプルを作った際には、java.library.pathの設定に失敗したので、どうしても難しい場合は一度環境変数pathに積んでみてください。
（コマンドプロンプトで実行されているので、PATH設定後、一度プロンプトを閉じて開きなおすことで有効になります。）

> もしよろしければ以下の画像のように普通にjarファイルを実行できないわけも教えてほしいです。

普通にというのは何をもって「普通」というのかという話が付きまといますが、統合デスクトップ環境でjarファイルをダブルクリックして動作しない（と思われる）件であれば、同じようにエラーを出力後、次の処理に移れないため、プロセスが終了しているだけじゃないですか？
なので、原因と結果が逆ですね。　ダブルクリック実行ができない⇒起動しないではなくて、そもそも環境がおかしくて起動できない⇒ダブルクリックしても起動しない（ように見える）のだと思います。

[image: 参考まで、私のPATHの設定状況です。]

Comment: jri.dllの場所をシステム変数PATHに入れたら実行できました。しかし、相変わらずjarファイをダブルクリックして実行というわけにはいかなかったです

Comment: 環境変数JAVA_HOMEが設定されていない。Oracle JRE入れていてそちらのJREが利用されている。大体考えられるのはこのぐらいでしょうか。。Windowsを使われているのならeventlogなど確認されたら追加の情報をえられるかもしれません。

Comment: あと、画像は引用難しくて、調べてくれる人のとっつきが悪くなる可能性があります。コード記述の機能などを使って工夫されると、もっとたくさんの人たちが回答してくれるかもです。